# Obtvse- Heroku database approaching row limit

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I recently set up an Obtvse blog with Heroku, and today I got an email saying that it was approaching its row limit with 7749 rows. I only have two blog posts! How is this possible? And should I be worried?

Comment: Did you look in your database to see which table was filling up?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably session data, or spam comments.  At some point Heroku will revoke your write access, but unless one is being outright abusive that is about as far as enforcement goes right now.  Perhaps you should consider profiling your use of rows in tables:

```
$ heroku pg:psql -a my-app
=> \dt

             List of relations
 Schema |       Name        | Type  | Owner 
--------+-------------------+-------+-------
 public | foo               | table | fdr
 public | schema_migrations | table | fdr
(2 rows)

=> SELECT count(*) FROM foo;
 count 
-------
     1
(1 row)
```